# div won't display on click of an image

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

No idea where the problem lies, tried various things and I'm not having any luck. I've done this successfully before in the past but now it won't work, any help would be great...

HTML snippet:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tableContent noBorderSides paddingAll"><img class="imgResize" src="images/emptyCircle.png" onclick="expandItem()"/>

<div id="Expand" class="hiddenDiv">

HELLO?

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function expandItem() {

if (document.getElementById("Expand").style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById("Expand").style.display = 'none';

}
else if (document.getElementById("Expand").style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById("Expand").style.display = 'block';

}
}
```

CSS:

```
.hiddenDiv {
display: none;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I may be completely wrong, but I think javascript style.display gets the display that is "inline" a.k.a not in a CSS file, try setting the display: none inline and see if that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial `display` that is set in your CSS won't be reachable from the `.style` property.

Do it like this:

```
function expandItem() {
    var expand = document.getElementById("Expand");
    if (expand.style.display == '') {
        expand.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else if (expand.style.display == 'block') {
        expand.style.display = '';
    }
}
```

Or a little shorter like this:

```
function expandItem() {
    var expand = document.getElementById("Expand");
    expand.style.display = (expand.style.display == '') ? 'none' : '';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) to get any style attributes associated with a given element. Notice, that the object returned is **read only**, so you'll want to use this for the initial `if` statement, and then set the style as you were doing above.

Answer (score 3):

You could just remove the class from the element that defines the hidden property and add when you want to hide:

```
if (document.getElementById("Expand").className == '') {
    document.getElementById("Expand").className = 'hiddenDiv';

}
else if (document.getElementById("Expand").className == 'hiddenDiv') {
    document.getElementById("Expand").className = '';

}
```

Do note that if you have other classes on that element you will need to do a little string manip rather than just a straight check and remove.

Comment: +1 I didn't notice the way the class was being used. replacing the class would be the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
//Temporary solution 
//Replace your javascript code with following code

if (document.getElementById("Expand").style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById("Expand").style.display = 'none';
}
else{
    document.getElementById("Expand").style.display = 'block';
}

//Note :- Javascript detect '' (empty) when it try to search display property for expand block
```

Answer (score 1):

@user1689607's answer is right if you need to just use javascript. If you have access to jQuery you can do it like so

`$("#Expand").toggle();`

And a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/P36YA/